# How to ACTUALLY use colors in output in lanugages like C?

Tags: c, colors, terminal, posix, portability

Pre-Note: By portable here, I mean cross-terminal, not cross-os or cross-platform. Different terminals support different codes for different colors (why btw?)

So, I want cool PORTABLE terminal colors. Searching around google, you find the same old options, but I don't want those. I want TERMINAL output. Like running `apt` produces brownish text sometimes, I don't want a window in ncurses, nor do I want to hardcode ANSI escape codes like `\033[31m`. Those are the two traditional options I do NOT WANT.

What I want is like this:

```
$ some program that doesn't really matter
blah blah earlier terminal output
$ colortest
Hello, World, but this part of the text would be in blue or something!
```

No window that erases my earlier terminal output or uses alternate screen buffer or anything. I want to do in C what I can do in bash with `tput setaf` and `printf`. But I can't find anything. There seems to be no library to do this. The only options I can find are "Use ncurses", which forces the window (as far as I know, I searched around for windowless ncurses but only got the windows download for ncurses), or "Hardcode ANSI codes", which also won't work. Is there any library to do this, or will I need to 
write something myself , querying things like `terminfo` or god forbid `termcap`? I haven't found this question being asked around earlier, forgive me if it has, but I am tires of the two unsatisfactory workarounds. My only option so far has been calling `tput` trough `popen` and such.

Comment: There is no portable option, you have to write different code for different OS

Comment: *"PORTABLE terminal colors"* is an oxymoron.

Comment: I mean portable as in works in any terminal. Tput automatically determines how to make a terminal display colors by knowing which terminal it is. Some terminals support only 8 or 16 colors. Some support 256. How do I know if they use extended ANSI? I don't know? By portable I don't mean cross-os, I mean cross-terminal.

Comment: `I mean portable as in works in any terminal` - no, there are not portable, they won't work on any terminal, only these which support it. Side note - use [ansi color codes](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+color+codes). There is ncurses, which is the most common terminal library.

Comment: Also, `tput` is part of ncurses, same for `terminfo` and `termcap` if you don't want to use `ncurses` don't use these utilities, they _are_ `ncurses`. `Is there any library to do this` - sending ansi color codes is not such complex thing to do, so you need a library to write that. Utilities just use ansi color codes.

Comment: Given that you aren't interested in cross-os solutions, you should specify the OS that you *are* interested in.

Comment: I know all these things. The problem with ncurses isn't ncurses, it's the fact that is forces me to CLEAR THE SCREEN and start a window. I do not want to do that. I want my program to output color into a terminal, without clearing it. I could use ANSI codes, but I would also need to somehow query terminfo to see which ansi codes the terminal even supports, which would normally be handled by curses/ncurses.

Comment: does every posix-compatible OS do?

Comment: ANSI escape codes is not part of POSIX. ANSI escape codes may not work on POSIX compatible OSes. I don't really get you. Just use the escape codes and go on. They are the the-facto standard (ECMA-48). If you want a library to send escape codes for you, [find some](https://github.com/topics/ansi-escape-codes?l=c) or write some.

Comment: You badly search because at least in stackoverflow querying "terminal color" gives you 250 result pages, of course some aren't directly related to your problem, but many of them answers it clearly.